# Fortran development on Windows

Tags: fortran

I'm not sure if this is a stupid question or not, but I'm thinking of learning to use fortran and was wondering if there a web site where fortran can be freely downloaded for windows, presuming that fortran is free?

Comment: FORTRAN is a language (and/or a standard describing a language). There are a number of FORTRAN compilers for various platforms, some free, some not.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran is a language - it is not something you can download. What you can download, though, is a fortran compiler. A compiler is a program that will turn code (written in a language, like Fortran) into machine code (which can then be executed by the operating system).

There are a number of compilers for Fortran. The GNU compiler suite is generally highly regarded (and free and open-source). You can download MinGW (http://www.mingw.org/), which gives you all the libraries and GNU compilers necessary to run a Fortran application on windows.

A basic tutorial on how to compile and run Fortran code in MinGW is available at http://www.stat.sc.edu/~habing/courses/740/mingw.html

Comment: OK, great. So, how is fortran different from something like matlab?

Comment: Well, the differences are a bit too long to list here. In general, the two are complementary: Fortran runs very fast as it is compiled, but generally, development in Fortran is relatively slow. In a scientific context, one might write the core, computationally expensive parts in Fortran and the rest (user interface, post-processing etc.) in a high-level language like Python or Matlab.